# How to connect to a remote server with my SSH keypair, through the new Windows 10 Linux bash?

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh, shell, powershell

I'm using the new Linux Bash Shell that have been recently made available on Windows 10 anniversary update.

This bash comes with a Linux mount point (`/mnt/c/Users/[username]`) on Windows, which is used as the Linux user home when you start the Linux bash, if I am correct.

But even though I have put my SSH keypair in the existing .ssh user folder (`/mnt/c/Users/[username]/.ssh`), it is not recognized when connecting to a remote server via SSH (`ssh username@distant-server.com`). It always aks for the username password instead of authenticating with public key, which is the case with my others clients.

Also, the public key is already in the `authorized_keys` file of the distant server.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bash profile can be acessed from Windows 10 by path:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\home\[bash-username]

You must put your SSH keypair in

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss\home\[bash-username]\.ssh

And don't forget about permissions on id_rsa. it should be set to 600, by running (in bash)

> cd ~/.ssh ; chmod 600 id_rsa

Answer (score 2):

Your home directory in bash isn't the same as mount point to your windows user folder (`/mnt/c/Users/[username]`). It will be the in the same format as Ubuntu would be: `/home/username`.

You can find where yours is by running `echo $HOME`. For example mine is `/home/john`

I can confirm adding a `.ssh` folder and copying your public key (normally `id_rsa.pub`) to `authorized_keys` using the command `cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys`, allows me to successfully connects to my SSH server, which is key authentication only.

The permissions on `authorized_keys` should be set to 600 (read and write to owner only), by running `cd ~/.ssh` and `chmod 600 authorized_keys`

Comment: has got the answer, we should also mentioned that id_rsa should be chmoded to 600

Comment: Thanks, it's very clear. But now that I've put my SSH keypair in the right directory and set the right permissions, it still doesn't connect without password to a remote SSH server. Could it be because my keypair is named `id_rsa_[myname]` and not simply `id_rsa`? It works like that on others clients of mine, though.

Comment: @Bolino I have just updated the post. I just had the same issue you were having. Your public key should be in the `authorized_keys` file. See last two paragraphs above for info.

Comment: My public key is already in the `authorized_keys` files of the distant machines, since I regularly connect to them using the same key, and with others clients (not Windows). So you mean put it also in the `authorized_keys` file of this local client - on Windows linux bash? I don't get exactly why, but I did it, and it is still not working.